# Jenkins unique ID and maven-dependency-plugin - how to remove unique id

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Hi everybody so problem is very simple I use something like this to process resources using maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-test</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.some.test</groupId>
                                <artifactId>test-webapp</artifactId>
                                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <outputDirectory>/testPath</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>test.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Idea is pretty simple to get artifactID **test-webapp** placed in some path. Problem is when I check manually in repository the artifact name is something looking like this:

**test-webapp-0.0.1-20160310.192210-35.jar**

I think problem is with this timestamp. Is there any way to auto remove it ? Maybe Maven have something that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Are you trying to publish to the repository without the timestamp? By default the timestamp is included with snapshot artifacts. And, is the problem not with the file copied using process-resources?

Comment: First it looks wrong copying a jar file in the process-resources phase to an aboslute path during a maven build furthermore you should check if you have set `overwriteSnapshots` etc. and you seemed to have missed `overwrite` etc. Check the docs..

Comment: @khmarbaise this path is only example what I'm looking for is simple I don't want to have something like this:

**D:\test\test-webapp-0.0.1-20160311.090400-36.jar**

but like this

**D:\test\test-webapp.jar**

Comment: As i mentioned please check the docs and you can use `stripVersion` ...In the majority of the cases copy goal in a maven build does not make sense...